# How to get response size for web requests in Azure Application Insights

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-application-insights

We have a ASP.NET Core WebAPI running with Application Insights using all default configurations (no custom telemetry reporting) and it reports telemetry to Azure Application Insights correctly, we can get the response time for each request from Performance view, in our case we also want to know the response size for each request to further improve the backend data serialization design but we are unable to get response size from existing data.

My question is: is the response size included in the default data collecting policy of Application Insights? If not how can we add this metric?

Frameworks: ASP.NET Core 2.1, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response size is not a part of default data collection policy in application insight. Though you can add your custom telemetry . For example of custom telemetry initializer, please take a look at below thread -

[View Post request Body in Application Insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686363/view-post-request-body-in-application-insights)