# Get RequestTelemetry (or ITelemetry) in derived ActionFilterAttribute using dependency injection

Tags: azure-application-insights

How to get the object of `ITelemety` object in an ASP.NET Core custom `ActionFilterAttribute` using dependency injection?

**Platform - .Net Core**

> What is required : ITelemetry object

Sample Code for reference

```
  public class CustomActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    private readonly ITelemetry telemetry;

    public CustomActionFilterAttribute(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        this.telemetry= telemetry;
    }
   }
```

I need to resolve `ITelemetry` object to add few Global Properties in the request context so that those can be logged in Request log. With above sample code, an exception is thrown when `ITelemetry` object is not being resolved by DI.

The `CustomActionFilterAttribute` is injected as shown below in startup.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
 {
       options.Filters.Add<CustomActionFilterAttribute>();
 });
```

Comment: why not use ITelemetry initializer? it's more easier for your purpose.

Comment: @IvanYang Thanks for your response. I require [ActionExecutingContext.ActionArguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext.actionarguments?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ActionExecutingContext_ActionArguments) to log the request arguments. The request arguments can not be retrieved in `ITelemetryInitializer`. Since, the custom filter has access to `ActionExecutingContext.ActionArguments` so using `ITelemetry` object the arguments can be logged.

Comment: @IvanYang - Currently, I've used `ITelemetryInitializer` to store `ITelemetry` object in `HttpContext.Items` and later retrieving the object in the custom `ActionFilterAttribute`. The implementation is done as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686363/view-post-request-body-in-application-insights/53776460#53776460)

Comment: You can put your comment as an answer, that would help others :).

Comment: The way it is implemented is more like a workaround instead of appropriate solution. The solution I'm looking is --- to inject `ITelemetry` object in custom `ActionFilterAttribute`. Is it possible?

Comment: Currently, I cannot find a way to inject ITlemetry object, but if I can figure it out, will let you know.

Comment: And .ctor injection of a `IHttpContextAccessor` (which will be null at times)  into a custom `ITelemetryInitializer` does not meet your needs because `ActionExecutingContext.ActionArguments` gives you more structured info on your arguments then `HttpContext.Request` ?

Comment: @ironstone13 - I did not get you what you are referring here. The mentioned linked solution is a workaround instead of actual **solution**. I'm also looking for a **solution** which has no dependency to inject `ITelemetry` object in `IHttpContextAccessor`. Is that possible?